# How do I count how many guesses it takes to get the correct number in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net

I have been struggling with this code for a while. I'm trying to make it so after the user gets the number right, the program counts how many tries it has taken them to get the number right. How can I do this?

```
Private Sub btnStart_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click
    'SELECTS THE SECTET NUMBER
    Randomize() 'WITHOUT rANDOMIZE, THE SAME SEQUENCE OF NUMBERS APPEARS EACH RUN
    secretNumber = Int(Rnd(1) * 1000 + 1) 'picks a random nubmer between 1 and 1000

    'sets the initial prompts
    Me.lblLow.Text = 1
    Me.lblHigh.Text = 1000
    Me.txtGuess.Focus()
    Dim count As Integer

    btnEnterGuess.Enabled = True
    btnStart.Enabled = False

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To count
        count = count + 1

    Next i

    Do
        count = count + 1
    Loop Until count = secretNumber
    MessageBox.Show("It took you " & i - 1 & " tries to get the number correct.")
End Sub
```

Comment: You are not giving the user a chance to enter their guess. You need a separate button that the user should click for each guess. It seems you have `btnEnterGuess`: make a handler for it, and each time it is executed counts as one guess.

Comment: You have a couple misunderstandings going on here. The biggest one is you’re never actually gathering the user input as far as I can tell

Comment: Also that for loop does nothing as count will be 0 initially, if it were set to more than 1 before the loop it would be an infinite loop or until you blew the limit of the integer variable type at least.

Comment: Two more points - it seems like there’s no reason for your `For` loop, and your `Loop Until` should use different logic. What you want is actually to loop until the user guesses correctly

Comment: I actually question if you need a loop, this is on a form so just increase the counter each button press until the answer is correct. No loop needed. Put a counter on the form, increase it for each incorrect button press, lock the guess button when the user is correct and unlock a reset button, the counter will be at the current guess number already.

Comment: It looks rather like you have made the common beginner mistake of writing code without knowing what it is supposed to do. Put your keyboard aside and pick up a pen and paper. Pretend that this is not a programming problem but rather a manual process. Pretend that you have to provide a set of instructions for someone to perform this manual process.  Write down those instructions.  Make sure they are detailed and clear. When you can follow those instructions and get the right result, you have an algorithm. Then, write code to implement that algorithm. That way, your code will make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I threw this piece of code togeather, hopefully it will help.
Something to note when writing this kinda code, is that all this code is running on a single thread (unless you declare it otherwise). This means your program will become unresponsive when you run that for loop.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim count As Integer = 0
    Dim answer As Integer = 0
    Dim GameRunning As Boolean = True
    Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As System.Windows.Forms.Message,
                                           ByVal keyData As System.Windows.Forms.Keys) _
                                           As Boolean
        'Gets all keystrokes on the fourm


        If GameRunning Then
            'converts keystroke to key ID and tests to see if the keystroke is the ENTER key
            If msg.WParam.ToInt32() = CInt(Keys.Enter) Then
                'try catch to prevent crash if text in entered
                Try
                    If txtAnswer.Text = answer Then
                        MessageBox.Show("Congratz! It took you " & count & " tries to guess the number!")
                    Else
                        txtAnswer.Text = ""
                        count = (count + 1)
                    End If
                Catch ex As Exception

                End Try
            End If
        End If
        'update label to show tries
        lblTries.Text = "Tries: " & count
        Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
    End Function
    Private Sub SetupOnLoad() Handles MyBase.Load
        Reset()
    End Sub
    Public Sub Reset()
        count = 0
        Randomize()
        answer = Int(Rnd(1) * 1000 + 1)
        txtAnswer.Text = ""
        lblTries.Text = "Tries: " & count
        GameRunning = True
    End Sub
    'the Reset() code is ran on the program launch and when you press the button to prepare the game.
    Private Sub Reset_Game() Handles BtnReset.Click
        Reset()
    End Sub
End Class
```

This code gets the user input in the text box. When the user presses ENTER, the program tests to see if its the correct number.
Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

I will try something like this, randomize need to be placed outside of the click

```
Public Class Form1
Dim count As Integer = 0
Dim answer As Integer = 0
Private Sub btnStart_ClicK(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click
    Randomize()
    answer = Int(Rnd(1) * 1000 + 1)

    btnStart.Enabled = False
    btnGuess.Enabled = True
End Sub


Private Sub btnGuess_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGuess.Click
    count += 1
    If answer = TextBox1.Text Then
        MessageBox.Show("It took you " & count & " tries to get the number correct.")
        btnStart.Enabled = True
        btnGuess.Enabled = False
        count = 0
        answer = 0
    Else
        TextBox1.Text = ""
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class